# streambuilder is rebuilding again and again when keyboard popup or closes

Tags: flutter, dart

Here I was stuck in a problem. I have a column of widgets with a stream builder and a text field. When i try to input some text, the keyboard pops up and then the stream builder rebuilds again or when the keyboard closes, the stream builder rebuilds again. As i am building a chat screen, I don't want to rebuild the stream builder again as it increases in number of reads.

Any sort of suggestions helpful.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please, show us a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and you'll get help

Comment: i think the question dont require a code to be posted any flutter or dart dev can easily understand the question

Comment: Please provide an example code of it, it will be better to understand how you write the code that occurs in rebuilding. Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Flutter calls the build() method every time it wants to change
>   anything in the view, and this happens surprisingly often.

You can pass the stream into the stateless widget

```
 MyApp({Key key, this.stream}) : super(key: key);
```

Or build the stream in the initState method if the widget is statefull.

```
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  post = buildStream();
}
```

Comment: Could you please give a little bit more info about the 'build stream in initState method'? Because I also have the problem my streambuilder rebuilds without wanting it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

What @TuanNguyen means by

> build the stream in the initState method

is the following, if for you are using Firestore for exemple:

```
class MyStateFullWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyStateFullWidget({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyStateFullWidgetState createState() => _MyStateFullWidgetState();
}

class _MyStateFullWidgetState extends State<MyStateFullWidget> {
  Stream _myStream;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _myStream = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(myCollection) ... .snapshots();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SomeUpperWidget(
      child: 
      StreamBuilder(
        stream: _myStream,
        builder: (ctx, snap) => ... ,
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Works for me...Thanks for sharing :)

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. I could not find simple alternative to avoid re-rendering without changing much code. So I ended up like this:

So in the Bloc class, first initiated a variable say
`streamStateIndex = 0;`
And wherever I am using
`sink.add(data)`
, I started using

```
streamStateIndex++;
sink.add({"data": data, "streamStateIndex":streamStateIndex});
```

And initiated another variable lets say `localStreamStateIndex = 0;` inside Stateful flutter class to compare streamStateIndex from bloc

And used inside StreamBuilder like this:

```
if (snapshot.hasData){
    if (localStreamStateIndex < snapshot.data['streamStateIndex']){
        updateLocalState(snapshot.data['data']);
        localStreamStateIndex = snapshot.data['streamStateIndex']; 
    }
}
```